# Android Upload Image From Drawable To Server

Tags: java, android, upload, multipart

Hey i'm making this app where user add attachment of image then send it to server. But the attachment is not mandatory, so user still can send it to server without add an attachment. If the user not add the attachment, it will send default image. And i want to send an image from drawable as the default image. I already do the code, but it's not working. My code below :

```
Resources resources = this.getResources();
        Uri otherPath = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + resources.getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.image) + '/' + resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.eimage));
        String path = otherPath .toString();
        imageFile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));

        File file1 = new File(path);
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file1);
        MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file1.getName(), requestBody);
```

it give me error :"open failed: ENOENT(no such file or directory).
do you have any idea to make this work?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you want to create image file from drawable  right?

Comment: yes, thats what i mean. do you have any suggestion? @JyotishBiswas

Comment: added a procedure in answer section , if you need more info or any other way then let me know

Answer (score 0):

here id is the identifier of your drawable resource. example : R.drawable.profile_image

Now using this input stream you can create a file

```
try
{
    File f=new File("your file name");
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(id);
    OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f);
    byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
    out.write(buf,0,len);
    out.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
}
```

Comment: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)